# How to use Ajax to get updated values from php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

As am new to Ajax am not understanding how to get changing variables values from php. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$pfstatetext = get_mypfstate();
$cpuusage= cpu_usage();
?>
<div id="show">
          <canvas id="chart-area2" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>

<script>

    var pieData2 = [
            {
                value: <?= $pfstatetext;?>,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "Red :"
            },
            {
                value: <?= $cpuusage; ?>,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "Green"
            }
];
window.onload = function(){
            var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
            var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);
             var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},10000);

                function myTimer() {
                 var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d"); 
                 var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);

}
        };


</script>
```

The above code redraws pie chart every 10 seconds but doesn't get updated values of '$pfstatetext' and '$cpuusage' every time the pie chart is redrawn after 10 seconds.

So what changes will i have to make using Ajax, so that the pie chart is drawn every 10 seconds with changing values of '$pfstatetext' and '$cpuusage'.

Comment: Make the AJAX call, and have the `onreadystatechange` function redraw the chart.

Comment: how to make Ajax call and where to enter onreadystatechange function? Am new to Ajax.

Comment: I'm not going to give an introductory class on AJAX, there are plenty of tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

to make ajax calls simply, use `jquery` javascript library.

I would need two files, one for data and one for drawing charts.

Data file (data.php) would look like this

```
<?php

    $pfstatetext = get_mypfstate();
    $cpuusage= cpu_usage();

    echo $pfstatetext."|||".$cpuusage;

?>
```

drawChart.php

```
function updateChart(){

    $.get( "data.php", function( data ) {

        data = data.split("|||");

        var pieData2 = [
                    {
                        value: data[0],
                        color:"#F7464A",
                        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                        label: "Red :"
                    },
                    {
                        value: data[1],
                        color: "#46BFBD",
                        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                        label: "Green"
                    }
        ];

        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
        var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);
        var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},10000);

    });
    setTimeout(updateChart, 1000);
}

window.onload = updateChart();
```

Comment: thanks, i will try this. What about myTimer() function? In your code the function definition is removed. Will i have to remove it?

Comment: $.get( "data.php", function( data ). After this statement what will the 'data' contain?

Comment: data contains whatever data.php would print